# Count to begin at 1

Tags: sql, db2

I want to value a column with a count. I am looking through the table to find the next count number. If a row does not exists I would like to begin the count with 1 rather than 0. Can someone assist me with my below query. If a row does exist then I would like to simply take the column 3 and add 1 to the next sequence number.

```
SELECT
COl1, 
Col2,
CAST((MAX(col3) + 1) AS SMALLINT) AS col3
FROM table1
GROUP BY col1, col2
```

Comment: Show sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a MAX() function that returns the highest value.  If you want to count the number of occurences (rows), you need to use the COUNT() function.

**Edit**

More details would be needed, but in SQL Server you could try something like this:

```
SELECT col1, col2, count(1) + 1 as col3
FROM table1
GROUP BY col1, col2
```

It would count the number of distinct pair of *col1* and *col2*, then add one to it and display it as *col3*.  From what I understand, you do not really need to use the current value of *col3*, since you are recalculating it.

Comment: thank you for your response. However, I do not need to count the occurances. rather I need to count the occrances of each combination of col 1 and col 2. and if that row does not already exist for the same combination of col 1 and col 2 then I have a job that inserts a new row and populates col 3 with either 1 or if an exists combination then it populates with the next available number in the sequence.

Comment: So the *col3* holds the current count of distinct (col1, col2)?

Comment: If i am understanding him correctly, his problem is if there is no row with the combination of COL1 and COL2 then he wants the output as 1. @knight944 is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you want all combinaison with 1 if one combinaison dont exist try this:

```
with combinaison as (
select distinct f1.col1, f2.col2 
from table1 f1 cross join table1 f2
)
SELECT f1.col1, f1.col2, ifnull(MAX(f1.col3), 0) + 1 AS col3
FROM table1 f1
GROUP BY f1.col1, f1.col2
union all
select f2.col1, f2.col2, 1 AS col3
from combinaison f2 left outer join table1 f3 on (f2.col1, f2.col2)=(f3.col1, f3.col2)
where f3.col1 is null
```